# Why would this Jquery scrollTop function not work?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've been looking through some of the other related questions on this problem, trying to form my own script, but its not working for some reason.  I'm wondering if anyone can give me any pointers.  I'm new to jquery, so I've probably overlooked something stupid.

I have #donate that's positioned fixed at the top left corner of the window, and inside it is a block of text in a p tag.  The header is dark, so I want the text light when the page is loaded, but as the user scrolls and leaves header where the background becomes light, I'd like to change the color of the text to be darker.

```
<script>

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 500) {

            $('#donate > p').css({"color": "#d2d0cb"});

    } else {

            $('#donate > p').css({"color": "#4e4e4e"});

    }
}


</script>
```

thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: yep, sorry.  I fixed it the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  I was missing a ); at the very end of the code, which was causing it not to work.